# Returning Map from a protected java method

Tags: java, compiler-errors, hashmap

```
protected void createIdUpdateMapForMapObjects()
{
    for (Iterator it = d_mapObjectList.iterator(); it.hasNext(); )
    {
        MapObject mapObj       = (MapObject) it.next();
        long      transientId  = mapObj.id();
        long      persistentId = g.getNewId();
        boolean minDPTObjectIdSet = false;
        long      minDPTObjectId ;
        long      maxDPTObjectId = g.upperBound();

        if(minDPTObjectIdSet == false) {
            minDPTObjectId = persistentId;
            System.out.println("min dpt" + minDPTObjectId);
            System.out.println("max dpt" + maxDPTObjectId);
            //insertDPTObjectId("minDPTObjectId", minDPTObjectId, "Starting change ID");
            //insertDPTObjectId("maxDPTObjectId", maxDPTObjectId, "End change ID");
            minDPTObjectIdSet = true;

        }

public Map<String, Long> getMinMaxDPTObjectId(String Name, long minmaxDPTObjectId) {
    Map<String,Long> minMaxDPTObjectId = new HashMap<String,Long>();

    minMaxDPTObjectId.put("minDPTObjectId",minDPTObjectId);
        //minDPTObjectId which i need to get from above method
    minMaxDPTObjectId.put("maxDPTObjectId",maxDPTObjectId);
        //same 

    return minMaxDPTObjectId;
}
```

I'm unable to return the values of minDPTObjectId and maxDPTObjectId to a Map that have to be used in another package
I think returning a map would be a good option but stuck ob how to do it

Comment: **1)** You don't call `getMinMaxDPTObjectId()` anywhere. **2)** is `[min|max]DPTObjectId` are variable instance or you didn't declare those ? **I see the declarations in the other method, not in the same scope**. **3)** If you just need to return two value, you could either use variable instance with getter or an home made instance `Holder`. To many question, could you see [ask] to improve this queston

Comment: Your code is missing curly braces, you try returning two things instead of just one (return minDPTObjectId,maxDPTObjectId;), from a method whose return type is void and which can thus not return anything. Read your introductory Java book, or the Java tutorial, about methods.

Comment: i have tried to solve the question but now i have to use this map in another package unable to do so

Answer (score 0):

```
public Map createIdUpdateMapForMapObjects()
{
    IdGenerator g = d_idm.getGenerator(OraclePropertyAdapter.NEXTID);    // could be null
    Map<String, Long> minMaxDPTObjectIdMap             = null;
    for (Iterator it = d_mapObjectList.iterator(); it.hasNext(); )
    {
        MapObject mapObj       = (MapObject) it.next();
        long      transientId  = mapObj.id();
        long      persistentId = g.getNewId();
        boolean minDPTObjectIdSet = false;
        long      minDPTObjectId ;
        long      maxDPTObjectId = g.upperBound();
        minMaxDPTObjectIdMap = new HashMap<String, Long>();
        minMaxDPTObjectIdMap.put("maxDPTObjectId",maxDPTObjectId);

        if(minDPTObjectIdSet == false) {
            minDPTObjectId = persistentId;
            minMaxDPTObjectIdMap.put("minDPTObjectId",minDPTObjectId);
            minDPTObjectIdSet = true;
}
           return minMaxDPTObjectIdMap;
```

does this appear good?